# Component won't render within another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, components, react-props

When I inject the modal component into the dom it renders fine. However, if I wrap that component and then render the new component into the dom. Nothing renders other than root.

Working component:

```
ReactDOM.render(( 
  <Modal visible={true}>
    <div> hello world </div>
  </Modal>
    ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Wrapped component that wont render:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <DeleteEntityModal />
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

This contains:

```
const DeleteEntityModal = () => {
  
  return (
    <Modal
      visible={true}
    >
      <div>
        hello world
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
  
export default DeleteEntityModal;
```

Comment: How do you import DeleteEntityModal in the `ReactDOM.render`'s file ?

Comment: like this:  import { DeleteEntityModal } from './Components/...';

Comment: But you have default expert for your component, so you should import as `import DeleteEntityModal from './FileName.js';`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are exporting `DeleteEntityModal` using `default` keyword, you need to import it like:

> import DeleteEntityModal from "./Components/..."

Or just remove the `default` keyword from your exportation.

Comment: I've just tried both suggestions and it's still not working unfortunately.

Comment: Are you familliar with React's hook ? can you add a simple useEffect in `DeleteEntityModal` with a mere `console.log("toto")` in order to check in the console if the component is called ?

Comment: Just tried. The components not being called at all. So must be a importing issue of some sort.

Comment: Did you tried to keep importing it like `import { DeleteEntityModal } from './Components/...';` with the `export default DeleteEntityModal;` ?